# Problem with hash256 in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sha256

when i use this code for generate an hash256 in my iPhone app:

```
 unsigned char hashedChars[32];
  NSString *inputString;
  inputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"];
  CC_SHA256([inputString UTF8String],
      [inputString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding ], 
      hashedChars);
  NSData * hashedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:hashedChars length:32];
```

The hash256 of inputString, is created correctly, but if i use a string like this @"\x00\x25\x53\b4", the hash256 is different from the real string with "\x" characters.
I think that the problem is in encoding "UTF8" instead of ascii.
Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you missing an x in @"\x00\x25\x53\b4"? Shouldn't it be @"\x00\x25\x53\xb4".

Comment: Hi pakzip, given one of your comments below the problem you are really trying to solve is a difference between a Python implementation and an Objective-C one. So may I suggest you add the following information to your question: (1) the input and output of a 'correct' example, where correct means the Python and Objective-C agree. (2) The input and output of an 'incorrect' example (show the input and the Obj-C output and the Python output). (3) The python source. With this information we should be able to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I would be suspicious of the first character, "\x00" - thats going to terminate anything that thinks its dealing with "regular C strings".

Not sure whether lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: takes that stuff into account, but its something I'd experiment with.

Comment: The problem is:If i try to insert "\x" characters, the resulting sha256 is incorrect and if i log the string with these characters, is different from equal string written in python for example. Excuse my crappy english.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the bytes with `[inputString UTF8String]` but the length with `[inputString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]`. This is obviously wrong. Moreover (assuming you mean "\xB4" and that it turns into something not in ASCII), "\xB4" is not likely to be in ASCII. The docs for NSString say

> Returns 0 if the specified encoding cannot be used to convert the receiver

So you're calculating the hash of the empty string. Of course it's wrong.

You're less likely to have problems if you only generate the data once:

```
NSData * inputData = [inputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CC_SHA256(inputData.bytes, inputData.length, hashedChars);
```